# I am getting this error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' in my index page

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I removed the IEnumerable from view page bit also i am getting the same error also i have kept breakpoint on index action of controller to check bu also could not solve.

This is my Index View

```
@model IEnumerable<BloodDonation1.Models.DonorModel>

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.Id)</th>
    <th>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.Id)</td>
```

This is my DAL page

```
  public class DonationContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<DonorModel> DonorModel { get; set; }


}
```

This is my controller View

```
    private DonationContext dc = new DonationContext();
    // GET: Donor
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View(); ;
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(DonorModel donorModel)
       {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            dc.DonorModel.Add(donorModel);
            dc.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
          }
        return View(donorModel);
        }
```

This is my Model View

```
 public class DonorModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }


    public string FirstName { get; set; }


    public string BloodGroup { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: From looking at the code above, you are never setting the Id.

Comment: Where does `dc` comes from? Add all relevant code and detailed error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never pass a value to your Index.cshtml.

This is how you pass a value to the view

```
private DonationContext dc = new DonationContext();
// GET: Donor
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = dc.DonorModel;
    return View(model); 
}
```

And in your View is a error.

```
<th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.Id)</th>
```

Will not work. Because your Model is a IEnumerable and it contains no definition of Id. (If you make a extension method its ok)